# SSH external tools nothing change for deleting content directory

Tags: phpstorm

I manage a PHP/Symfony application into Vagrant with PHPStorm IDE.

I would like to clear directory cache with just a shortcut in my IDE PHPStorm.

*I want to launch this command in my vagrant system :*

```
(into Working directory) $/bin/rm -rf cache/*
```

I result is erase all the files and directory into cache directory as I like it.

*For that, I create SSH External Tools in PHPStorm like that :*

[image]

*The return console is :*

[image]

It seems to be good with code return 0. But I real it do nothing erase action in my directory.

**How can I delete content directory into SSH External tools PHPStorm feature ?**

**EDIT :**

I confirm that if I replace `/bin/rm` by `/bin/ls` the external SSH command return me the right content of remote directory

Comment: It could be a nice idea to check if this command is really being executed in the working directory. For example, you may temporarily replace "rm" with something like "ls" for debugging purposes to check the current context.

Comment: I edit my issue and confirm that /bin/ls return right content of my remote directory